# Can't find Emulators when setting up Xamarin in VS community 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, installation

I'm trying to setup for Xamarin development, but can't find `Visual Studio Emulator for Android and Windows 10 Mobile Emulator (Creators Update)` under `Individual Components` ( those items in red in the screenshot below). All I can see the first 2 under the `Emulators` list `Google Android Emulator(API Level 23) and Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM)`.

My computer specs:

- 8GB RAM
- 64-bit Windows 10 Home

Note*: the screenshot is from the instructions that I found online, not from my computer.

[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6v9R.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Visual Studio Emulator for Android is using Hyper-V which requires Windows 10 Pro. But you can use the Google Android emulator which is using the mentioned Intel HAXM.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to modify my VS enterprise 2017 15.2 (26430.13) and checked the Individual components – Emulators, the options are the same as yours, please check this following screenshot. The photo you shared is a previous VS 2017 version and looks different with the latest version, you should not follow it.

[image]

Since your OS is windows 10 Home version, you need to upgrade to the professional version, please refer to this: [System Requirements for the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/system-requirements-for-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android) and it requires the 64-bit version of the Pro edition of Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows 10 or higher to use the VS Emulator for Android.